# Glass is opaque, won't show fluid inside (blender 2.83)

Tags: blender

I simply want to be able to see things inside my glass tube including fluid. A little like [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IhvCaTqfL64&t=477s).
Currently, the glass is reflective yet opaque, like a mirror. [This is the tube in wireframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFxLi.png), you can clearly see the liquid and inflow object inside. However, [rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1056.jpg), they are both hidden. You can see I used the glass BSDF shader.
I seem to also be having issues getting my liquid to be a mesh instead of rainbow dots but I think that's a separate problem and doesn't explain why my glass is opaque?
Thanks in advance,
Yosef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You go 
Step 1 material tab 
Step 2 principled BSDF 
Step 3 turn transmission up to 1 
Step 4 render properties tab 
Step 5 tick screen space reflection 
Step 6 drop down and tick refraction 
Step 7 material tab 
Step 8 scroll down and tick screen space refraction 
Step 9 turn roughness down to 0 to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things that could be the issue here but I'll provide some insight on some of the most likely culprits. This could be caused by:

- If you're using Cycles to render, make sure that the number of bounces for transparent and translucent materials is at least 2, otherwise the glass would render as black.
- Make sure the lighting in your scene is rendering as intended, as insufficient light or a poorly placed camera can make glass look just like a mirror surface.
- Similarly, check the material properties of the liquid inside the tube. If the liquid is being rendered as black/opaque, it's also possible that it is causing the tube to act as a mirror.

These possible causes all assume that the materials are set up correctly - and it would be easier to help diagnose the problem with a little more information on your material setup (the nodes), the rendering engine you're using (Cycles, Eevee, etc.), and information about the lighting in your scene.